# Gson serialize with two List types in a single JSON object

Tags: android, android-json, jsonserializer, gson

I have two types of list to bind the request using Gson library. I tried in a way, it is working as excepted. But I want to know whether we have any default procedure to serialize the lists.

I tried below and working. But this is not the way to implement. Searching for better solution.

```
class Request{
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("ListC")
    private List<TypeOne> mList;

    public Request(List<TypeOne> listOne, List<TypeTwo> listTwo){
        this.mList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listTwo.size(); i++) {
           // Adding the Typetwo values in TypeOne model class - Not best approach
           listOne.get(i).setAmount(listTwo.get(i).getAmount());
           listOne.get(i).setName(listTwo.get(i).getName());
           listOne.get(i).setType(listTwo.get(i).getType());
        }
        this.mList.addAll(listOne);
    }

    public String getJsonString(){
         Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(TypeOne.class, new Serializer())
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateSerializer())
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .create();

    JsonObject in = new JsonObject();
    in.add("in", gson.toJsonTree(this));

    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
    obj.add("req", in);

    return obj.toString();
    }
}
```

Is anyone faced the similar issue and fixed this, please direct me to get it done. Trying from long back to find better solution.

Output JSON:

```
{
"list":[
    Obj{
    "Type_1_object_1":"value",
    "Type_1_object_2":"value",
    "Type_1_object_3":"value",
    "Type_2_object_5":"value",
    "Type_2_object_6":"value"
    },
    Obj{
    "Type_1_object_1":"value",
    "Type_1_object_2":"value",
    "Type_1_object_3":"value", 
    "Type_2_object_5":"value", 
    "Type_2_object_6":"value"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Simply speaking, you just want to zip/merge lists in the output JSON?

Comment: Yes, two types of lists to be added in a single jsonobject using Gson library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two approaches that are different at the very base:

- Using [data transfer objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) letting you control the result using object mapping
- Using type adapters (and possibly streaming, but I'm not sure if it's possible in Gson for you case)

Let's assume the following data models:

```java
final class User {

    final String username;
    final String contact;

    User(final String username, final String contact) {
        this.username = username;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

}
```

```java
final class FooBar {

    final int foo;
    final int bar;

    FooBar(final int foo, final int bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

And suppose these two should be zipped/merged.

#### Data transfer objects

The result DTO might look as follows:

```java
final class UserFooBarDto {

    final String username;
    final String contact;
    final Integer foo;
    final Integer bar;

    private UserFooBarDto(final String username, final String contact, final Integer foo, final Integer bar) {
        this.username = username;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    static UserFooBarDto userFooBarDto(final User user) {
        return new UserFooBarDto(user.username, user.contact, null, null);
    }

    static UserFooBarDto userFooBarDto(final FooBar fooBar) {
        return new UserFooBarDto(null, null, fooBar.foo, fooBar.bar);
    }

    static UserFooBarDto userFooBarDto(final User user, final FooBar fooBar) {
        return new UserFooBarDto(user.username, user.contact, fooBar.foo, fooBar.bar);
    }

}
```

Then the result might be accomplished using the following code:

```java
static void main(final String... args) {
    final List<User> users = ImmutableList.of(
            new User("john.doe", "john.doe@mail.com"),
            new User("alice.bob", "alice.and.bob@mail.com")
    );
    final List<FooBar> fooBars = ImmutableList.of(
            new FooBar(1, 2),
            new FooBar(3, 4),
            new FooBar(5, 6),
            new FooBar(7, 8)
    );
    final List<UserFooBarDto> zippedList = zip(users, fooBars, zipper);
    final String json = gson.toJson(zippedList);
    System.out.println(json);
}

private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

// It's a good idea to create such objects once, and use them everywhere where necessary not instantiating them over and over
private static final IZipper<User, FooBar, UserFooBarDto, List<UserFooBarDto>> zipper = new IZipper<User, FooBar, UserFooBarDto, List<UserFooBarDto>>() {
    @Override
    public List<UserFooBarDto> collectTo() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public UserFooBarDto zip(final User user, final FooBar fooBar) {
        if ( user != null && fooBar != null ) {
            return userFooBarDto(user, fooBar);
        } else if ( user != null ) {
            return userFooBarDto(user);
        } else if ( fooBar != null ) {
            return userFooBarDto(fooBar);
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }
};

// A simple zipper interface that would tell where collect the zipped result to and how a zipped result element should be combined from
private interface IZipper<I1, I2, O, C extends Collection<O>> {

    C collectTo();

    O zip(I1 i1, I2 i2);

}

private static <I1, I2, O, C extends Collection<O>> C zip(
        final Iterable<? extends I1> list1,
        final Iterable<? extends I2> list2,
        final IZipper<? super I1, ? super I2, ? extends O, C> zipper
) {
    final C collection = zipper.collectTo();
    final Iterator<? extends I1> iterator1 = list1.iterator();
    final Iterator<? extends I2> iterator2 = list2.iterator();
    while ( iterator1.hasNext() || iterator2.hasNext() ) {
        final I1 i1 = iterator1.hasNext() ? iterator1.next() : null;
        final I2 i2 = iterator2.hasNext() ? iterator2.next() : null;
        final O o = zipper.zip(i1, i2);
        collection.add(o);
    }
    return collection;
}
```

#### Type adapters

Another, more "dynamic", approach is using type adapters that may be somewhat harder to implement, but probably easier to use.

```java
static void main(final String... args) {
    final List<User> users = ImmutableList.of(
            new User("john.doe", "john.doe@mail.com"),
            new User("alice.bob", "alice.and.bob@mail.com")
    );
    final List<FooBar> fooBars = ImmutableList.of(
            new FooBar(1, 2),
            new FooBar(3, 4),
            new FooBar(5, 6),
            new FooBar(7, 8)
    );
    final ZippedList<User, FooBar> zippedList = new ZippedList<>(users, fooBars);
    final String json = gson.toJson(zippedList, userAndFooBarZippedListType);
    System.out.println(json);
}

// TypeToken types are immutable types and can be safely assigned to static final fields
private static final Type userAndFooBarZippedListType = new TypeToken<ZippedList<User, FooBar>>() {}.getType();

// Gson instances are thread-safe and can be instantiated once too more saving instantiation time
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ZippedListTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();

// A special container class to let Gson pick a proper type adapter
private static final class ZippedList<T1, T2> {

    private final List<T1> list1;
    private final List<T2> list2;

    private ZippedList(final List<T1> list1, final List<T2> list2) {
        this.list1 = list1;
        this.list2 = list2;
    }

}

private static final class ZippedListTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // Not a class we must handle ourselves? Let Gson pick another best type adapter itself
        if ( !ZippedList.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            return null;
        }
        // Narrowing down the scope of @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") and making the type adapter to take care for nulls automatically
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new ZippedListTypeAdapter<>(gson).nullSafe();
        return typeAdapter;
    }

}

private static final class ZippedListTypeAdapter<T1, T2>
        extends TypeAdapter<ZippedList<T1, T2>> {

    private final Gson gson;

    private ZippedListTypeAdapter(final Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final ZippedList<T1, T2> zippedList)
            throws IOException {
        // Write [ to the output
        out.beginArray();
        final Iterator<? extends T1> iterator1 = zippedList.list1.iterator();
        final Iterator<? extends T2> iterator2 = zippedList.list2.iterator();
        // Iterate over two sequences trying to merge their respective elements JSON representations
        while ( iterator1.hasNext() || iterator2.hasNext() ) {
            final T1 i1 = iterator1.hasNext() ? iterator1.next() : null;
            final T2 i2 = iterator2.hasNext() ? iterator2.next() : null;
            // This is not very efficient because it builds in-memory JSON trees thus consuming memory
            // It would be nice if it would be possible to decorate JsonWriter to control its beginObject and endObject
            // The latter control would help to suppress { and } at the top level, and delegate the real serialization to Gson with the decorated JsonWriter
            // But JsonWriter constructor requires a Writer, not at JsonWriter, and we do not have where to obtain a writer instance from
            // So we can just merge the trees...
            final JsonElement tree = mergeInto(gson.toJsonTree(i1), gson.toJsonTree(i2));
            gson.toJson(tree, out);
        }
        // Write ] to the output
        out.endArray();
    }

    @Override
    public ZippedList<T1, T2> read(final JsonReader in) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    // JSON object types dispatching party...
    private static JsonElement mergeInto(final JsonElement e1, final JsonElement e2) {
        if ( e1.isJsonNull() ) {
            if ( e2.isJsonObject() ) {
                return mergeInto(e1.getAsJsonNull(), e2.getAsJsonObject());
            } else {
                throw new AssertionError("TODO: " + e2.getClass());
            }
        } else if ( e1.isJsonObject() ) {
            if ( e2.isJsonObject() ) {
                return mergeInto(e1.getAsJsonObject(), e2.getAsJsonObject());
            } else {
                throw new AssertionError("TODO: " + e2.getClass());
            }
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError("TODO: " + e1.getClass());
        }
    }

    // A bunch of specialized mergeInto overloads letting javac to pick the best one
    private static JsonObject mergeInto(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final JsonNull jsonNull1, final JsonObject jsonObject2) {
        return jsonObject2;
    }

    private static JsonObject mergeInto(final JsonObject jsonObject1, final JsonObject jsonObject2) {
        for ( final Entry<String, JsonElement> e : jsonObject2.entrySet() ) {
            jsonObject1.add(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
        return jsonObject1;
    }

}
```

Both examples produce the following JSON (prettified):

```
[
    {
        "username": "john.doe",
        "contact": "john.doe@mail.com",
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": 2
    },
    {
        "username": "alice.bob",
        "contact": "alice.and.bob@mail.com",
        "foo": 3,
        "bar": 4
    },
    {
        "foo": 5,
        "bar": 6
    },
    {
        "foo": 7,
        "bar": 8
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm not able to test the TypeAdapter code. private static final Type userAndFooBarZippedListType = TypeToken.getParameterized(ZippedList.class, User.class, FooBar.class).getType(); creating error

Comment: @AbishR It might be introduced in the recent Gson versions. I'm using 2.8.0. However, I have just edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Lyubomyr Shaydariv, it worked. But the json should be build inside a single object. It is creating two separate json objects. From both the lists it should create one object.

Comment: @AbishR Well. you might re-configure it if necessary... Doesn't your desired JSON output match the result above structurally?

Comment: Re-configure JSON? we can't. Your code gives the output as [{}],[{}]

Comment: @AbishR I meant reconfiguring either `Gson` instance or your POJO mappings, not JSON. `Your code gives the output as [{}],[{}] -- sorry, but where? From a list of [{a},{b}] and [{1},{2},{3},{4}] it gives [{a1},{b2},{3},{4}] -- merged exactly according to the output in your question _before_ you edited it.

Comment: @AbishR Also, if you want it to be _a part_ of an object, why not just creating a wrapper object mapping with a `private ZippedList<A, B> list` field?

Comment: The same json format is already there in my question, just to explain briefly I modified its names. Your solution giving two seperate lists

Comment: @AbishR I must be blind if I can't see it. Anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake. I mistakenly added an list. But I am getting only one model's output after merging. Second Lists data is not binding. I will check and update you. Thank you again for quick responses @Lyubomyr Shaydariv.

Comment: I am doing with Type Adapters, In the class ZippedListTypeAdapterFactory it was reaching last line return typeAdapter; After it was not going anywhere. Nothing is added in the list. It was not reaching ZippedListTypeAdapter class

Comment: @AbishR Are you sure you're passing a `ZippedList`?

Comment: Thank you so much @Lyubomyr Shaydariv. It worked. I was used the gson inside a function instead of global or before zipping. I was researching this from last week. Your answer helped me lot. Is there any way is there is skip some values while merging or creating the json. From both list I want to leave some properties. Like setFieldNamingStrategy in Gson

Comment: @AbishR You're welcome! Not out of box, unfortunately: since this is a custom type adapter, you have to implement it yourself because Gson is not aware of how this type adapter works internally (you can easily implement it using the strategy design pattern that could handle the JSON trees and remove unnecessary key/values).